# When trying to set an AlarmManager event, previous one is resetting with new time and the new one is not getting triggerred

Tags: android

Here is my code which I tried, Steps.

1) creating an AlarmManager event by calling AM.Set( ) method suppose with time X.

2) creating another AlarmManager event suppose with time Y.

Result = first event is triggered at time Y in place of time X. and second is not triggered at all.

```
AlarmManager AM =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Constants.ALARM_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_DATA1, data[0]);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_DATA2, data[1]);
long selectedTime = Long.parseLong(data[2]);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent,0);
AM.set(AlarmManager.RTC,selectedTime, pi);
```

Am I doing something wrong? I need to trigger all the events .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first and second `Intents` are equivalent, and so you wind up with the same `PendingIntent` object as a result of your `getBroadcast()` call. Either:

- Use a unique `requestCode` (2nd parameter to `getBroadcast()`), which I *think* will clear this up, or
- Do something to have a unique action, data (`Uri`), categories, or MIME type on each `Intent` (extras being different are not sufficient)

Comment: by adding requestcode different for each item, is worked for me, Thanks 
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, count++, intent,0);

Answer (score 0):

By adding a count variable which will automotically increase when try to getBroadcast. it    is working now.

```
AlarmManager AM =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Constants.ALARM_ACTION_MESSAGE);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_NUMBER, data[0]);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_BODY, data[1]);
long selectedTime = Long.parseLong(data[2]);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, count++, intent,0);
AM.set(AlarmManager.RTC,selectedTime, pi);
```